# Start gulp task from another node.js script

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm using script like this:

run.js:

```
var gulp = global.gulp  = require('gulp');
require('./gulpfile.js');

//interaction
gulp.start('zip');
```

gulpfile.js:

```
global.gulp = global.gulp || require('gulp');

gulp.task('zip', function () {});
```

And start: `node run.js`

I need it because I need collect some data via `inquirer.prompt()` before task start.

Everything works, but console freeze cursor after script end(in PHPStorm).

I don't understand why. If I run task via gulp, it's ok.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `callback` to your `zip` task?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Aperçu in the comments, try letting gulp know that you're done your task.

Change

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {});
```

to

```
gulp.task('zip', function (done) {done()});
```